# Windows 7 wireless icons (tray)

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, icons

I have not found an answer to a simple question: I know the bars means the quality of a WiFi connection. What does it mean when there is 3 monitors connected? Thanks! I have not found this anywhere!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're referring to? I don't remember seeing one that is 3 monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you're connected to an ad-hoc network (a temporary network between computers often used when no router is available) vs an infrastructure-based network (with a router and/or a wireless access point).